# Bones moving incorrect things on mesh

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

I've added bones to this mesh that I downloaded online and for some reason when I move some specific bones it moves other stuff, like eyebrows. I'm not that experienced yet I know a few things here & there, so it would be nice to explain it in simple terms.

There are 4 images showing whats happening https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VS9d.jpg

(I've seen others mention vertex groups in other threads but I don't know what a vertex group is...)

Cheers!

Comment: You have to learn about rigging, vertex groups, and weight paint. There are a lot of tutors on Youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of wrong weight paint.

Solution: In pose mode select a bone and Shift select the model and switch from object mode to weight paint mode you will see the model with blue and red color.

The red color represents the area which is under the effect of the bone in the Tool panel select subtract and paint on the parts you don't want the bone to move which are the (eye brows I guess) wallah and watch the tutorial by blender on weight paint basics on youtube ..